# Como pegar o nível do microfone usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, inputstream

Oque eu gostaria é uma forma de conseguir pegar o nível do microfone que eu defino no Windows.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu uso esse código para pegar o stream

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()
.then(function(stream) {
  console.log(stream)
})
```

Porém a partir desse objeto stream eu preciso desse nível, ou algo que me aponte que o microfone não está em 100% de capacidade.

Comment: Isso não é possível heimm ... via JS não tem como pegar essa Info do SO, o que você pode tentar fazer é verificar o dB conforme alguém fala no Mic e pressupor que está alto de mais ...

Comment: E como eu iria pressupor isso ? qual seria o parâmetro para saber disso ?

Comment: com base em um threshold adaptável, fazendo uma pré analise de alguns segundos no mic e definindo se o dB está acima do que vc considera alto ....